# JComboBox With Larger Drop Down Width

Tags: swing, jcombobox

The problem: I have a combo box that needs to fit into a fixed space as part of a Swing application.  However, its contents may be quite long.  I'd like the box itself to be a fixed size, truncating contents.  When the down arrow is clicked, though, I'd like it to act similar to an HTML select and show a box that is long enough to fit the longest entry as the drop down.  The ListCellRenderer may be the way to go on this one; I'm not sure.

It also may be that I need some sort of implementation of javax.swing.plaf.basic.ComboPopup and my own ComboBoxUI.  I've dug through the SwingUtilities code to understand how the DefaultListCellRenderer does its calculations.  It uses a JLabel, and the BasicLabelUI calls SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel (eventually in the call stack) which does the clipping.  BasicComboPopup, the only implementation of ComboPopup in the Java 6 code I was digging through, seemed to delegate to:
    JList.computeVisibleRect(Component c, Rectangle visibleRect)

Has anyone done this before?  Any pointers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the width of a JComboBox dropdown list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956003/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-jcombobox-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good starting point :)

SteppedComboBox – http://web.archive.org/web/20070607203953/http://www.crionics.com/products/opensource/faq/swing_ex/JComboBoxExamples1.html

Comment: @CostisAivalis fixed that with Wayback machine.

Comment: Link broken again. Both of them.

Answer (score 1):

JComboBox by anonymous with variable-width dropdown. Note that this is Metal LAF only.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

/**
 * @version 1.0 12/12/98
 * updated 2012-02-18 to include @Overrides and other Java needs
 */
class SteppedComboBoxUI extends MetalComboBoxUI {
  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Override
  protected ComboPopup createPopup() {
    BasicComboPopup popup = new BasicComboPopup( comboBox ) {

      @Override
    public void show() {
        Dimension popupSize = ((SteppedComboBox)comboBox).getPopupSize();
        popupSize.setSize( popupSize.width,
          getPopupHeightForRowCount( comboBox.getMaximumRowCount() ) );
        Rectangle popupBounds = computePopupBounds( 0,
          comboBox.getBounds().height, popupSize.width, popupSize.height);
        scroller.setMaximumSize( popupBounds.getSize() );
        scroller.setPreferredSize( popupBounds.getSize() );
        scroller.setMinimumSize( popupBounds.getSize() );
        list.invalidate();            
        int selectedIndex = comboBox.getSelectedIndex();
        if ( selectedIndex == -1 ) {
          list.clearSelection();
        } else {
          list.setSelectedIndex( selectedIndex );
        }            
        list.ensureIndexIsVisible( list.getSelectedIndex() );
        setLightWeightPopupEnabled( comboBox.isLightWeightPopupEnabled() );

        show( comboBox, popupBounds.x, popupBounds.y );
      }
    };
    popup.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleParent(comboBox);
    return popup;
  }
}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SteppedComboBox extends JComboBox {
  protected int popupWidth;

  public SteppedComboBox(ComboBoxModel aModel) {
    super(aModel);
    setUI(new SteppedComboBoxUI());
    popupWidth = 0;
  }

  public SteppedComboBox(final Object[] items) {
    super(items);
    setUI(new SteppedComboBoxUI());
    popupWidth = 0;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SteppedComboBox(Vector items) {
    super(items);
    setUI(new SteppedComboBoxUI());
    popupWidth = 0;
  }


  public void setPopupWidth(int width) {
    popupWidth = width;
  }

  public Dimension getPopupSize() {
    Dimension size = getSize();
    if (popupWidth < 1) popupWidth = size.width;
    return new Dimension(popupWidth, size.height);
  }
}
```