# Is it possible to have a child element larger than its parent?

Tags: java, combobox, autocomplete, panel, textfield

I have a textfield within a fixed-width panel of 200 pixels. This textfield is used to search amongst products, once we type in something, it shows the results in a combobox, here's how it works:

```
public void setupAutoComplete(final JTextField txtInput) {
    final DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    cbInput = new JComboBox(model) {
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(super.getPreferredSize().width, 0);
        }
    };
    txtInput.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    txtInput.add(cbInput, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

I need the combobox to be as large as the longest result shown, but I can't get it to be larger than the textfield for now, is there a way to do it without having to make the textfield larger and therefore the panel where's it's contained also?

Comment: Would a scrollpane help you here?

Comment: preferably I would like to be able to see the whole thing without having to scroll within the combobox

Comment: So you want the combobox to grow but the panel that contains the combobox shouldn't grow? How should that work visually? Or should the panel grow only if needed? In that case use a layout manager and set the maximum size of the text field. You might also want to look into MigLayout which makes those layouts a lot easier.

Comment: let's say my panel is a column, I don't want the panel to change size at all, I need the combobox "overflow" to be shown over the panel if that's possible.

Comment: Is this what you want then? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956003/how-can-i-change-the-width-of-a-jcombobox-dropdown-list  If so you might be interested in SwingX' `JxComboBox`.